# What exactly is 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers' used for?

Tags: botframework

Amazingly, I can't find any documentation for this, and Google tells me nothing. Yet tantalizingly, it is used in the many sample projects supplied by Microsoft to showcase Bot Framework. What is a 'fiber' and what should I use it for in a bot context?

Comment: In which samples you are seeing that? The Fiber is mostly internal and won't be directly used in your bot.

Comment: Hi Ezequiel. I'm currently looking at the 'CreateNewConversationBot', for example, in the BotBuilder-Samples repo on github. It appears to be tied in with the use of Autofac somehow. In the MessagesController ctor, 'SetField' is called, which is something to do with Fibers. I presume it's something to do with controlling object lifetimes via the DI, but I'm not clear on it. (Then again, I loathe DI with a passion, so I'd say that's a given anyway :) )

Comment: No, SetField is just a helper function that will throw a NullReferenceException if the value is null https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Fibers/SetField.cs#L45

Comment: That may be so, but I'm still none the wiser as to the point of it. It's clearly something to do with the Autofac DI though. Why would I want to call Fibers.SetField in my 'messages' bot controller at all?

Comment: Nothing to do with Autofac (I worked on the sample ;)). What we are doing there is just check if the ILifetimeScope (which yes, is something of Autofac) is null or not. We are doing that because in the Post method we are using the scope and thus we are checking it beforehand

Comment: Why do I need ('for internal use') Fibers just to check for null? Why I might want to use FiberModule's.Key_DoNotSerialize over Key_SurrogateProvider, and for what? What on earth is a Fiber in the first place? And what's it doing in my Messages controller?Not having a go at you Ezequiel - thanks for taking the time to reply - it's just frustrating trying to guess these things.

Comment: Check for null; no need to use that method; you can use your own; it doesn't add anything. The DoNotSerialize key is basically allow dialogs to reference non-serializables services: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#how-can-i-reference-non-serializable-services-from-my-c-dialogs. Again that's an string so if you put the string instead of the enum it will be fine too.